# Given $x\cdot x =x$ Prove that it is a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have seen some threads related to this, but I want to know whether my approach is correct.

> Given $R$ a ring and that $\forall$ $x \in R, x\cdot x=x$. Then prove
>   that it is a commutative ring.

My try:

Considering $$(x+y)\cdot(x+y)=x\cdot x+x\cdot y+y\cdot x+y\cdot y$$  we get

$$x+y=x+y+x\cdot y+y\cdot x$$

using Cancellation laws:

$$x\cdot y=-(y\cdot x)$$
$\implies$

$$x\cdot y=y\cdot (-x)$$

We have $$x\cdot x=x$$

$$(-x)\cdot (-x)=-x$$

But $$(-x)\cdot (-x)=x$$

So $$x=-x.$$

Hence $$x\cdot y=y\cdot x$$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: It seems perfectly fine to me. Just a LaTeX tip: use \cdot instead of an actual dot for products.

Comment: so in a ring can every element be its own additive inverse? any example

Comment: Yes an example is polynomials mod 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine! Just for fun, here is a another one using the same ideas.

---

Let $a,b \in R$. We have that  \begin{align} 
(a+b)(a+b) &= a\cdot a + a \cdot b + b \cdot a + b \cdot b\\
&= a + a \cdot b + b \cdot a + b\\
&\overset{*}{=} a + b
\end{align}
and using the Cancellation Law in $*$ gives us that $a\cdot b = -(b \cdot a)$, so $b \cdot a = -(a \cdot b)$. But then

\begin{align}
(a\cdot b)\cdot (a\cdot b)&= a \cdot (b \cdot a) \cdot b\\
&= a \cdot (-(a \cdot b)) \cdot b\\
&=a \cdot ((-a)\cdot b)  \cdot b\\
&= (a \cdot (-a))\cdot (b \cdot b)\\
&=(-a)\cdot b\\
&= -(a \cdot b)\\
&= a\cdot b
\end{align}

(where the last equality follows from $(a\cdot b)\cdot (a \cdot b) = a \cdot b$) and so $a\cdot b = - (a \cdot b)$ together with $b \cdot a = -(a \cdot b)$ give us that $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$. But $a$ and $b$ were chosen arbitrarily, so $R$ is indeed a commutative ring.